# Condition variables in c++, how do I use them properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock, condition-variable

I am trying to implement a worker object (that is a thread that waits for tasks and terminates only when destroyed), but I am having trouble using the `std::condition_variable`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

    
    
class Worker {
public:
    Worker(Worker&&) = delete;
    Worker(const Worker&) = delete;
    Worker() 
        : stop(false)
        , thread(&Worker::worker_thread, this)
    {}
    void push(std::function<void()> _f) {
        std::unique_lock lock(thread_mutex);
        task = std::move(_f);
        new_task.notify_one();
    }
    ~Worker() { /* not implemented yet */ }
private:
    void worker_thread() {
        std::unique_lock lock(thread_mutex);
        while (true) {
            new_task.wait(lock);
            if (stop) return;
            task();
        }
    }
    std::atomic<bool> stop;
    std::function<void()> task;
    std::thread thread;
    std::mutex thread_mutex;
    std::condition_variable new_task;
};
```

I came up with this example here that currently does not work with gcc:

```
int main() {
    Worker t;
    t.push([] { std::cout << "Hello from worker" << std::endl; });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        t.push([i] { std::cout << i << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

If run the code i get this output:

```
terminate called without an active exception //(because destructor yet to be implemented)
9
9
9
9
9

.
.
. and so on 

9
```

So here is how my code is supposed to work:

when a `Worker` object is constructed it spawns a thread that executes the `worker_thread` function.
This function locks the `thread_mutex` and is supposed to unlock it only when it waits for the condition variable.

When a task is pushed, the `push` function tries to lock the mutex, and it should only when it can, and that is when the `worker_thread` is waiting on the task with the condition variable.

So if the thread is waiting, `push` should be able to aquire the lock and move the new task in the `task` buffer, then notify the condition variable, waking up the thread.

One hint is that this code:

```
int main() {
    Worker t;
    t.push([] { std::cout << "Hello from worker" << std::endl; });

    //for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    //    t.push([i] { std::cout << i << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

says hello forever, well at some point it crashes, but should only print once and then wait for the next task.

This is even more weird because my initial thought was that there was an issue with multiple pushes being performend one after the other, maybe that could cause some problems with the lock, but in this last example i call `push` only once and still i have issues.

Can someone understand where the problem is?

Comment: You need to put a condition in `wait` that ensures that you really want to proceed with the task and when starting the task, you should unlock the mutex and relock it prior to next wait. Currently, nothing really prevents the worker queue to run continously. And there is no point in `stop` being atomic, if you modify it without locking the mutex it will most probably be a bug.

Comment: @kabibesadagat look at the Worker() constructor

Comment: @ALX23z so doesn't wait() wait for a signal? if the signal is not being sent, how doesn't that block execution?

Comment: @ugo_capeto wait doesn't necessarily wait for a signal. It can wake up randomly. Perhaps, lack of unlocking causes it to believe it never needs to sleep.

Comment: @ALX23z so I pretty much always have to use a condition variable with a check because it does not wait for a signal necessarely? then what is the point of calling wait without a check lambda? (if there is a point at all) where can i find more informations about this behaviour? Thank you for your kindness by the way, really helped.

Comment: `wait` without lambda is used to implement `wait` with lambda. Also one could desire a more complicated scheme but it is rarely the case.

Comment: The exception occurs in `Worker` destructor, called at the closing brace of `main`. It tries to destroy `std::thread` while it's still running.

Comment: It is possible that all `push` calls complete *before* the thread starts running and gets to `wait` call. Since it missed all `notify_one` calls, and doesn't check for any condition (like e.g. `task != nullptr`), it'll just wait forever. Even setting aside this startup issue: if you make two `push` calls in quick succession, the second one may overwrite the task set by the first one, before the thread wakes up and actually runs the first task. You need a queue of pending tasks.

Comment: When using a condition variable, it's important to be clear about what condition this variable guards. This condition may already be true before waiting (then you shouldn't wait), or may be false after (then you should get back to waiting). `wait` with a predicate implements this logic: `wait(lock, pred)` is equivalent to `while (!pred()) wait(lock);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that works on both examples:

```
class Worker {
public:
    Worker(Worker&&) = delete;
    Worker(const Worker&) = delete;
    Worker() 
        : stop(false)
        , task(nullptr)
        , thread(&Worker::worker_thread, this)
    {}
    void push(std::function<void()> _f) {
        std::unique_lock lock(thread_mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return !task; });
        task = std::move(_f);
        new_task.notify_one();
    }
    ~Worker() {
        std::unique_lock lock(thread_mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return !task; });
        stop = true; 
        new_task.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
        if (thread.joinable()) 
            thread.join();  
    } 
private:
    void worker_thread() {
        std::unique_lock lock(thread_mutex);
        while (true) {
            cv.wait(lock, [this] { return task || stop; }); //
            if (stop) return;
            task();
            task = nullptr; // reset task for check
            new_task.notify_one();
        }
    }
    bool stop; // does not need to be atomic
    std::function<void()> task;
    std::mutex thread_mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread thread; // moved to bottom
};
```

the main problem I had is that i did not understand how condition variables worked.

A condition variable does NOT wait for a signal, it waits for a condition.
So once in a while the condition variable will "wake up" the thread, and it is the user's responsability to check if the condition is met.
When using a condition variable it is important to check for a condition, otherwise it will wake up from time to time and run what ever is after.
So one way to do this is this:

```
while (!condition)
    cv.wait(lock);
```

or this, using lambdas:

```
cv.wait(lock, [] { return condition; });
```

So `cv.notify_one()` is simply a hint that a condition might have changed, not an order to wake up the thread.

Furthermore, I have to be careful with initialization, as in my previous code the thread was initialized before the condition variable and the mutex, wether that made a difference or not is unclear in this case, it probabily did.
Member variables are initialized in the order in which they are declared.

At last, I also need to check for another condition in the `push` and the destructor. I need to see in both that the task is not valid, or set to `0` or `NULL`.

This is because if it is set to NULL, it means that the `push` function can safely modify the task that is not being used by the `worker_thread`.
The destructor does a similar thing, it needs to see if the thread has finished executing the last task before destroying it, setting the `stop` flag to `true`,
that is because the worker checks if the flag is set before executing the task.

That's all, thank you all for your kind help, I hope this question is helpful for all programmers that need to understand condition variables.

Comment: A couple of issues in the implementation: (1) one shouldn't call `notify_one/all` when the mutex is locked as it leads to behavior "hurry up and wait". (2) when the task is called, the mutex shouldn't be locked. It is fixed by moving the `task` into a local variable, unlocking mutex, and executing the task. (3) it is not a desired behavior to have people wait on pushing the task in most circumstances. But let OP deal with fixing the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Read about [**Initialization order**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). You run a thread when `thread_mutex` and `new_task` are not initialized yet. Running `worker_thread` with uninitialized members is undefined behavior.
2. `Worker` construction, pushing a task, destruction can happen before the thread worker starts, and the worker waits for the condition variable forever. You should first use the condition variable in the opposite direction to signal the constructor about the running worker.

Comment: that could be the problem, do i simply need to initialize them in the constructor before initializing the thread?

Comment: Just move `std::thread thread;` to the bottom.

Comment: @ugo_capeto The order in which members are listed in the constructor initializer list doesn't matter. Members are always initialized in the order in which they are defined in the body of the class.

Comment: moving the thread to the bottom stops the infinite printing but still crashes the program, maybe for the reason that @ALX23z suggested in his comment under my post.

Comment: Yes, this is a second reason. I wanted to post about it too, but it was longer to post on mobile: construction, push, destruction can happen before the thread worker starts, and the worker waits the condition forever.